# How does the "Module: CLI (argparse)" template in Pydev work?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, argparse

How does the "Module: CLI (argparse)" template in Pydev (Eclipse) work?
When I run it, it just prints out the usage help and exits, and my code doesn't get executed. As I understand it from usage output, I need to pass a 'path' argument. But I got the same result when setting the path to something.

The template looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
'''
test1.test -- shortdesc

test1.test is a description

It defines classes_and_methods

@author:     user_name

@copyright:  2015 organization_name. All rights reserved.

@license:    license

@contact:    user_email
@deffield    updated: Updated
'''

import sys
import os

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter

__all__ = []
__version__ = 0.1
__date__ = '2015-07-31'
__updated__ = '2015-07-31'

DEBUG = 1
TESTRUN = 0
PROFILE = 0

class CLIError(Exception):
    '''Generic exception to raise and log different fatal errors.'''
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(CLIError).__init__(type(self))
        self.msg = "E: %s" % msg
    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.msg

def main(argv=None): # IGNORE:C0111
    '''Command line options.'''

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    else:
        sys.argv.extend(argv)

    program_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    program_version = "v%s" % __version__
    program_build_date = str(__updated__)
    program_version_message = '%%(prog)s %s (%s)' % (program_version, program_build_date)
    program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]
    program_license = '''%s

  Created by user_name on %s.
  Copyright 2015 organization_name. All rights reserved.

  Licensed under the Apache License 2.0
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Distributed on an "AS IS" basis without warranties
  or conditions of any kind, either express or implied.

USAGE
''' % (program_shortdesc, str(__date__))

    try:
        # Setup argument parser
        parser = ArgumentParser(description=program_license, formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument("-r", "--recursive", dest="recurse", action="store_true", help="recurse into subfolders [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", dest="verbose", action="count", help="set verbosity level [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-i", "--include", dest="include", help="only include paths matching this regex pattern. Note: exclude is given preference over include. [default: %(default)s]", metavar="RE" )
        parser.add_argument("-e", "--exclude", dest="exclude", help="exclude paths matching this regex pattern. [default: %(default)s]", metavar="RE" )
        parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version=program_version_message)
        parser.add_argument(dest="paths", help="paths to folder(s) with source file(s) [default: %(default)s]", metavar="path", nargs='+')

        # Process arguments
        args = parser.parse_args()

        paths = args.paths
        verbose = args.verbose
        recurse = args.recurse
        inpat = args.include
        expat = args.exclude

        if verbose > 0:
            print("Verbose mode on")
            if recurse:
                print("Recursive mode on")
            else:
                print("Recursive mode off")

        if inpat and expat and inpat == expat:
            raise CLIError("include and exclude pattern are equal! Nothing will be processed.")

        for inpath in paths:
            ### do something with inpath ###
            print(inpath)
        return 0
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ### handle keyboard interrupt ###
        return 0
    except Exception, e:
        if DEBUG or TESTRUN:
            raise(e)
        indent = len(program_name) * " "
        sys.stderr.write(program_name + ": " + repr(e) + "\n")
        sys.stderr.write(indent + "  for help use --help")
        return 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        sys.argv.append("-h")
        sys.argv.append("-v")
        sys.argv.append("-r")
    if TESTRUN:
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
    if PROFILE:
        import cProfile
        import pstats
        profile_filename = 'test1.test_profile.txt'
        cProfile.run('main()', profile_filename)
        statsfile = open("profile_stats.txt", "wb")
        p = pstats.Stats(profile_filename, stream=statsfile)
        stats = p.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative')
        stats.print_stats()
        statsfile.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DEBUG` mode, the `-h` added to the `sys.argv`.  That has priority over all other inputs, producing the `help` message (and exit).

Comment out thE line that adds the `-h` to DEBUG to see the effect of your arguments (plus `v` and `r`).

In other modes (except those defined in the `main`), the commandline arguments should have effect (i.e. the ones in `sys.argv`).

Comment: As you said, the problem was that -h (which is added in DEBUG) causes the program to exit. Commenting it out resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You're running in DEBUG mode and all you do in that mode is append stuff to `argv`:

```
if DEBUG:
        sys.argv.append("-h") # <-- that is your problem
        sys.argv.append("-v")
        sys.argv.append("-r")
```

Since you're adding an "unknown" argument, when you run:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

it raises an exception. You can either solve it by removing that line (preferably), or by using:

```
parser.parse_known_args([])
```

(the latter is a patch to hide the underlying issue and should be used with cautious. IMO it shouldn't be used in this case!).

Comment: `-h` argument is added automatically when you create the `parser`.  When `-h` is added to the `sys.argv` is prints the `help` and exits.  No error.

Comment: @hpaulj "-h argument is added automatically when you create the parser" - true. Yet, when it's added to `sys.argv` it causes the parser to crash. It's easy to wrap `parser.parse_args()` in a `try/except` block and see that it's happening. As to "why" it is happening: as I said, it's not defined as `parser.add_argument(...)` and hence it's considered as a "new" argument and as such, `parse_args()` doesn't know how to handle it and raises an exception, but [parse_known_args()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) was created for that purpose

Comment: I mean the `argparse.ArgumentParser()` includes a `add_argument('-h', action='help')` command.

Comment: @hpaulj again, true (I don't disagree about this one) :) That said, when the user tries to "manually" set `-h` in `sys.argv` it creates a conflict with the the help `-h` and it causes `parse_args()` to raise an exception. As for handling that exception - as I wrote, best to avoid it, but if, for any reason, the user insists on doing that (which he shouldn't) then `parse_known_args()` will be able to cope with it.